# Opening a different frame with a button in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to open the menu frame using a button on the main frame.  I added an event to the button and I tried calling the other class but it keeps giving me an error of ":: expected after this token"

This is my main frame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class Main extends JFrame {

public static JPanel mainPane;
public final JButton menuButton = new JButton("New button");

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Main frame = new Main();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Main() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    mainPane = new JPanel();
    mainPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(mainPane);
    mainPane.setLayout(null);
    menuButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Menu.main(String[] args);
        }
    });
    menuButton.setBounds(76, 89, 104, 32);
    mainPane.add(menuButton);
}
}
```

And this is my menu frame

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Menu extends JFrame {

public static JPanel menuPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Menu frame = new Menu();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Menu() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    menuPane = new JPanel();
    menuPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(menuPane);
    menuPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel menuTitle = new JLabel("Menu");
    menuTitle.setBounds(194, 11, 46, 14);
    menuPane.add(menuTitle);

}
}
```

Comment: Please post full error output

Comment: This problem has been discussed at least 0 times.

Comment: The error is due to `Menu.main(String[] args)`, use solution provided by Fast Snail

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

change your action event to this.no need to call main method .create a new instance of Menu class instead.

```
 menuButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Menu menu = new Menu();
            menu.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

if you relly want to call main method then use

```
menuButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           Menu.main(new String[0]);
        }
    });
```

the error is here

```
Menu.main(String[] args);//error
```

this is not a correct way of passing arguments to a methods.this is declaration of parameter list.

you can correct error by changing it to ,

```
String args[] = null;
Menu.main(args);    //correct
```